# Authenticate converged applications(MSA) on Azure Webapp

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

We are planning to setup a multi-tenant azure web api which will be invoke by a client app which is registered as converged app with MSA but now in Azure AD. The client app owner dont have Azure AD on thier side. And the client belongs to different tenant.
Can someone please explain how the client will invoke our azure ad web api as client isn't registered as azure webapp.
We have setup .net core azure webapp

Answer (score 0):

You need to consent to the web API from your client app tenant first. To consent to the web API, you could follow this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/client-app-tenant/oauth2/authorize?client_id=api-client-id&redirect_uri=api-reply-url&response_type=code&prompt=admin_consent
```

By this, a service principal will be created in your app tenant for the API, allowing you to assign app permissions to the web API in your app tenant.